# Unable to move drone object after adding background image in Blender 2.80

Tags: animation

I have added drone 3D object and trying to move it along axis after adding a background image.
I want to move drone over the background image,but image itself is moving .
I am selecting the drone and pressing i and then selecting co-ordinates.
I was able to move the drone before adding bg image.
Please find the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting with 2.80, adding a background image actually adds an empty object that displays the image. This object can be selected and moved like any other, even if it is set to draw its image behind scene objects.

I would suggest making the empty non-selectable. In the [outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/editors/outliner.html), select the empty. If the cursor is not visible in the [restiction columns](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns), you can enable it in the filter menu by clicking on the funnel in the header. You can also find the same option in the objects visibility properties.

[image: object selectability options]